# Which of the statements, with respect to the triangle, is correct?

Tags: geometry

The answer should be I) and II), but I have only been able to solve II).

It is supposed that I must solve this only with knowledge of secondary elements of the triangle and criteria of congruence of the triangle.

Exercise:

[image]

My development:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will prove that $\Delta ACG \cong \Delta FCE$. This would immediately imply that $GC=FC$ as required

Since you have solved part 2, you know that the angles $\angle BAC$ and $ \angle DEC$ are equal. Moreover, it is given in the question that $AC=CE$. Since the two angles are vertically opposite, $\angle GCA = \angle ECF$. Thus the two triangles are congruent and we are done

Comment: You mean to $FCE$(you wrote $FCG$ that isn't a triangle) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've made the edit

Answer (score 0):

$\angle{BAC} \cong \angle{DEC}$ means $BA || DE$ which leads to  $\angle{BGC} \cong \angle{DFC}$ and  $\angle{AGC} \cong \angle{EFC}$. Use ASA congruency to show that $\triangle{BGC} \cong \triangle{CDF}$